# What is the best way to build an insulation wall out of Ytong in my attic?

Tags: insulation, attic

I live in a brick house from the 1930s, which has been modernized to meet the German KFW110 standard.
The only thing missing are the attic end walls, which are only one brick thick and according to planning, they need a layer of 100mm thick Ytong style stones on it to reach the standard.
The floor is made from wood planks with a supporting beam below it, which I intend to replace with 22mm OSB.

Can I build this wall on top it or should I rather attach it to the wall somehow?

Comment: A picture would help

Comment: Are these "Ytong style stones" the only option available to you, or are they the commonly suggested option given a certain set of preconditions (which don't necessarily apply to your situation)? Surely there are other ways to meet the KFW110 standard than using one specific product?

Comment: @brhans Pretty sure you are right, the standard will allow arbitrary insulation products

Comment: @RohitGupta Anything in particular?

Comment: @brhans Of course it could be done with other (lighter) products , but I want to go that route because of the sustainability of these bricks.